# PHP and postgreSQL not returning data to AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, postgresql

I am using AJAX - HTML - Javascript & PHP in order to extract data from postgreSQL/postGis database.
I attach below the codes of two files (html & php codes): query_nest_ajax.html & query_nest_ajax.php.
However, after the execution of the html file, nothing happen. I think I missing something.
Any help is welcome.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="btg">
            <option value='BTGTN'>btgtn</option>
            <option value='BTGKS'>btgks</option>
            <option value='BTGTS'>btgts</option>
        </select><br>
        <button type="filterSubmit">Submit</button>
        <hr>
        <div id="resultTable"></div>
        <br>
    </body>

    <script>
        $("#filterSubmit").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:'query_nest_ajax.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:{
                    btg: $("#btg").val()
                },
                success: function(response){
                    $("#resultTable").html(response);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

php code:

```
<?php
$bs = $_POST['btg'];
$db = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=Reseau_Gaz','postgres','steg1993');
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT id_bal, btg, ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_TRANSFORM(geom_cqg,4326),5) FROM balise_reperage WHERE btg = :bs ");
$params = ["bs"=>$bs];
$sql->execute($params);

echo "<table class='table table-striped'>";
echo "<tr><th>Balise N°</th><th>Base Transport</th><th>Géométrie</th></tr>";
while ($row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $field=>$value){
        echo "<td>{$value}</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

?>

Comment: `$("#filterSubmit").click(...)` but you have nothing with id `filterSubmit`. Your button has `type="filterSubmit"`, which isn't a valid "type" for a button - I assume therefore that `type` was a typo for `id`?

Comment: Many thanks Robin. Indeed, it is a typo. As you mentioned "id" instead of "type